# Offline / online based web application with permission to access hardware feature

Tags: android, database, web-services, web, smartphone

I would like to ask a few questions.

1) If I want to store the form data in local storage of phone, then the application will auto sync the data with the online database. So, any method to do that?

2) Is there anyway for web application to access the hardware features such as gps, camera and others?

3) If not, can native application provide sync function?

Comment: You will have to write your own sync function in your app code. If you want to access hardware features , web apps may not be able to access but hybrid apps can access . For creating hybrid apps you can have a look at PhoneGap.

Comment: So, can PhoneGap/ Apache Cordova work with the external / online database such as MySql, Oracle 11g?